# Area51 RSS feed bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, feed

The user feeds on Area51 are using an incorrect path. You can see on my page:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/40898/codewaggle

The paths for the feed links are using "proposal" where they should be using "user".

Current path for the "user feed' link at the bottom of my page:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/proposal/40898

The correct path:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/40898

---

An additional problem is that the "responses" feed doesn't work.

On nine sites that I've checked, adding "/responses" to the end of the feed path gives you a feed of the items that appear in your responses tab:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/40898/responses

Comment: Area 51 is not a normal site, so /responses isn't supposed to work (it never has), will take a look at the user feed link though.

Comment: I wondered about the responses, when I was looking at this problem, I noticed that the tabs are laid out differently than most (all?) other sites. Thanks for looking into the path issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user feed link will be fixed in a build of Area 51 going out in a few minutes, the responses tab is intentionally not there as it's a totally different code base and was never implemented on Area 51.